# Tracking down emberjs component actions not firing

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an EmberJS component, who's action(s) isn't getting fired at all. I have made a basic JSFiddle example with the versions of the libraries which I use, and that application doesn't have the issue.

This leads me to the conclusion that I have included something in my stack (there is ember-auth etc) which interferes with the component actions.

Here is a simple example, which doesn't work in my stack:

```
{{! component class }}
// ...
  actions: {
    accept: function(){ console.log("accepted") }
  }

{{! list-item.handlebars }}
<button {{action 'accept'}}>click to accept</button>
```

So my question becomes: How do I track down the component action, to see what part of the application is hindering the action(s) from executing correctly?

#### Update (14/11)

My component is named `App.ListItemComponent`, and the handlebars template is named `list-item.handlebars`.

Comment: How are you naming your component class and your component .hbs file?

Comment: Can you post the fiddle?  One approach would be to see what the call stack is when it's working and set breakpoints on your app based on that.

Comment: @chopper I have updated with component and hbs names. But the component is displaying fine; actions are just not fireing.

Comment: @AmirT I simply changed the versions from the generic emberjs fiddle. In this case, the actions still worked. So it's something in my particular stack. I'm including a lot of stuff, so I need some way to track how a component action is bubbling up through the stack..